# Can I create a /dev/sda image while it's being used by the running Linux?

Tags: linux, backup, dd, disk-image

I'm running a GNU/Linux system, but the hard drive is failing, so I want to make a complete disk image to copy it later to a replacement hard drive.

Can I run the dd command from system itself?

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/external/disk/sda.dd
```

Should I rather shutdown the system, boot a LiveCD and do this when the disk is not actively used by a running operating system?

What could possibly go wrong if I don't?

Comment: I think you technically can but you don't want to. The resulting image will most probably be inconsistent. [This is what happens](https://www.google.pl/search?q=panorama+fail) when you sequentially create an image of an object that can change its state during this operation.

Comment: Indeed, the image might be inconsistent, but if you're using a journalling filesystem (like ext3/4), then changes are that you'd be able to recover these inconsistencies. If you want the best guarantee of a consistent image then it's best to copy it while no partitions on the disk are mounted, e.g. from a live CD.